# Finding the next largest integer

Tags: ruby, algorithm, refactoring

I want to find the next largest integer out of integers that consist of the characters in a given integer. If the given integer is the biggest, return `-1`.

```
def next_bigger(n)
  perm = n.to_s.chars.sort.permutation.to_a.uniq
  to_return = []
  perm.each do |x|
    to_return.push(x.join)
  end
  tracker = to_return.find_index(n.to_s)
  if to_return[tracker + 1] != nil
    return to_return[tracker + 1].to_i
  else
    -1
  end
end
```

This code works. I don't know how to make it lighter. Right now it takes forever to run. Where would you start?

Comment: The appropriate place for improving code that already works is http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I disagree with @Mark. The essence of this question is whether there is a better algorithm than the use of brute force. Viewed that way, not only is it appropriate for SO, but it's quite an interesting question. Christopher, consider changing your question by removing the code and just saying you have attempted to solve it by enumerating permutations of the number's digits, but that takes far too long, and ask if there is a more efficient way of solving the problem. Also, in your first line change "characters" to "digits" and give a not-too-small example number and the desired return value.

Comment: I'll admit, it could arguably be on-topic here. But I maintain that it is more on-topic at codereview, since this is essentially a refactoring for efficiency question which is common there. On the other hand, it gets more eyeballs here.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The [tag:refactoring] tag tilts it towards being off-topic for Stack Overflow. It makes it a non-specific request for improvements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to obtain a highly efficient procedure.

**Code**

```
def next_largest(n)
  nxt = nl(n.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i))
  return nil if nxt.nil?
  nxt.map(&:to_s).join.to_i
end

def nl(arr, remaining_digits=arr.sort)
  if arr.size == 1
    return (remaining_digits.first > arr.first) ? remaining_digits : nil
  end 

  first = arr.first
  remaining_arr = arr.drop(1)

  remaining_digits.each_index do |i|
    d = remaining_digits[i]
    rest =
    case i
    when 0 then remaining_digits.drop(1)
    when remaining_digits.size-1 then remaining_digits[0..-2]
    else [*remaining_digits[0..i-1], *remaining_digits[i+1..-1]]
    end
    return [d, *rest] if d > first
    if d == first
      arr = nl(remaining_arr, rest)
      return [d, *arr] if arr
    end
  end
  nil    
end
```

**Examples**

```
(1..10000).to_a.sample(10).sort.each do |n|
  v = next_largest(n)
  print "%4d => " % n
  puts(v ? ("%4d" % v) : "No next number")
end
 647 =>  674
1137 => 1173
4010 => 4100
4357 => 4375
6542 => No next number
6832 => 8236
6943 => 9346
7030 => 7300
8384 => 8438
9125 => 9152

next_largest(613_492_385_167)
  #=> 613492385176
```

All of these calculations took a small fraction of a second.

**Explanation**

(to be provided as time permits...)